# MySQL's ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering if it's possible to have multiple primary keys.... as in....

```
id       name       description      slug
```

Is it possible for me to do an `ON DUPLICATE KEY` query relating to the `slug` when I have an `id` column that's auto incrementing....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You just need to create a UNIQUE index for slug.

Comment: Sweet - so as long as I don't include `id` in the insert query it'll only check `slug` (assuming `slug` exists)

Comment: Yup.  You should never include the ID on an insert anyway, since it is a autoincrement.  If you do, you wind up satisfying the potentially disasterous condition in my comment on Ajay's response.

Comment: Oh and one thing more even... for speed, I believe you may need to add a standard index to slug as well for reading.

Comment: Green: a unique index is sufficient, it will be used searching.

Comment: @MarkR  I wasn't sure if it wound up in the keycache.  Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create composite primary key or can create the index for another field.

Comment: From my understanding, a composite primary key would make the ID field no longer unique in and of itself.  Although you'd generally be ok, the first time you try to INSERT and accidentally add in id as one of the values, your DB would wind up in a problematic state.

Comment: I don't think that would do what the OP wants.